# SQL Server inconsistent results over 2 columns using = and <>

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to replace a manual process with an SQL-SERVER (2012) based automated one. Prior to doing this, I need to analyse the data in question over time to produce some data quality measures/statistics.

Part of this entails comparing the values in two columns. I need to count where they match and where they do not so I can prove my varied stats tally. This should be simple but seems not to be.

Basically, I have a table containing two columns both of which are defined identically as type INT with null values permitted.

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   WHERE COLUMN1 is NULL
```

returns zero rows

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE 
   WHERE COLUMN2 is NULL
```

also returns zero rows.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
```

returns 3780
and

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

returns 3780 rows.

So I have established that there are 3780 rows in my table and that there are no NULL values in the columns I am interested in.

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   WHERE COLUMN1=COLUMN2
```

returns zero rows as expected.

Conversely therefore in a table of 3780 rows, with no NULL values in the columns being compared, I expect the following SQL

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   WHERE COLUMN1<>COLUMN2
```

or in desperation

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   WHERE NOT (COLUMN1=COLUMN2)
```

to return 3780 rows but it doesn't. It returns 3709!

I have tried SELECT * instead of SELECT COUNT(*) in case NULL values in some other columns were impacting but this made no difference, I still got 3709 rows.

Also, there are some negative values in 73 rows for COLUMN1 - is this what causes the issue (but 73+3709=3782 not 3780 my number of rows)?

What is a better way of proving the values in these numeric columns never match?

Update 09/09/2016: At Lamaks suggestion below I isolated the 71 missing rows and found that in each one, COLUMN1 = NULL and COLUMN2 = -99. So the issue is NULL values but why doesn't

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 is NULL
```

pick them up? Here is the information in Information Schema Views and System Views:

ORDINAL_POSITION COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH  IS_NULLABLE

1                ID          int       NULL                      NO

..  ..  ..  ..  ..

7                COLUMN1     int       NULL                      YES

8                COLUMN2     int       NULL                      YES

CONSTRAINT_NAME

PK__TABLE___...

name    type_desc   is_unique   is_primary_key

PK__TABLE___...    CLUSTERED   1   1

Suspect the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH of NULL must be the issue?

Comment: are those the exact queries you are using?, is it a table or a view?

Comment: @AaronBertrand don't understand what you mean. They are both int types which can be null.

Comment: @Lamak they are physical tables not views

Comment: well, if everything is as posted, then I can't find an explanation

Comment: Is this problem reproducible?

Comment: Genuine request @AaronBertrand .... in the question I stated "Basically, I have a table containing two columns both of which are defined identically as type INT with null values permitted." .... how should I phrase in future?

Comment: Yes @scsimon. Repeatedly and consistently.

Comment: I think the question was worded fine. I'm also baffled like @Lamak.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I completely skipped the third paragraph, though to be more clear it can't hurt to put table definitions (at least CREATE TABLE with the relevant columns and constraints) and identify a few of the rows that match and a few that don't.

Comment: I still can't think of a reason **why** this could happen, assuming that everything is as said in the question. If you do a `SELECT * INTO OtherTable FROM CurrentTable`, does this behavior repeats itself?

Comment: Ok @AaronBertrand.

Comment: Yes @Lamak it still happens if I select into another table.

Comment: This is just too weird. Can you post the table definition and a sample of the 81 rows that don't appear with the `COLUMN1 <> COLUMN2` filter?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't have the CREATE table I am just using the tables.  Will the results of query on details from Information Schema Views and System Views do?

Comment: @Hilary It won't hurt. And can you post some sample data of the 81 rows that aren't in the result?

Comment: Bingo @Lamak, all of column 1 is NULL and all of column 2 is -99. So why are my very first two select statements above not picking up NULL values?

Comment: that shouldn't happen at all. That's why I suspect `column1` is **not** an `INT`  and has the literal string `'NULL'` stored in it

Comment: @Hilary I'm just going to ask to clear all doubts. Are you absolutely sure that you are using `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IS NULL`  instead of `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = NULL`?

Comment: @Lamak Suspect the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH of NULL must be the issue?

Comment: @Hilary that's the expected result for a numeric data type

Comment: Certain @Lamak. Even tried both to make sure I wasn't missing something. Just ran again and can 100% confirm definitely using "is NULL" which is not picking up the NULL values. The data was read in from a spreadsheet originally so I'm away to see if I can eyeball the data services job used for creation.

Comment: @Hilary This is just so unusually weird. When you see those `NULL`s in management studio, is the background yeollow-ish?, or white?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123011/discussion-between-hilary-and-lamak).

Comment: /shrug You can right-click any table in SSMS > Object Explorer and select Script > AS CREATE to > new window/clipboard etc. You don't need to be actively creating a table to show us a create table script.

Comment: What does this return: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column1 IS NULL OR column2 IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the exhaustive comment chain above with all help gratefully received, I suspect this to be a problem with the table creation script data types for the columns in question. I have no explanation from an SQL code point of view, as to why the "is NULL" intermittently picked up NULL values.

I was able to identify the 71 rows that were not being picked up as expected by using an "except".

i.e. I flipped the SQL that was missing 71 rows, namely:

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 <> COLUMN 2
```

through an except:

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   EXCEPT
   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 <> COLUMN 2
```

Through that I could see that COLUMN1 was always NULL in the missing 71 rows -  even though the "is NULL" was not picking them up for me when I ran

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IS NULL
```

which returned zero rows.

Regarding the comparison of values stored in the columns, as my data volumes are low (3780 recs), I am just forcing the issue by using ISNULL and setting to 9999 (a numeric value I know my data will never contain) to make it work.

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   WHERE ISNULL(COLUMN1, 9999) <> COLUMN2
```

I then get the 3780 rows as expected. It's not ideal but it'll have to do and is more or less appropriate as there are null values in there so they have to be handled.

Also, using Bertrands tip above I could view the table creation script and the columns were definitely set up as INT.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the count based on the below query using left join.

```
--To find COLUMN1=COLUMN2 Count
--------------------------------
SELECT COUNT(T1.ID)
FROM TABLE T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 ON T1.COLUMN1=T2.COLUMN2
WHERE t2.id is not null

--To find COLUMN1<>COLUMN2 Count
--------------------------------
SELECT COUNT(T1.ID)
FROM TABLE T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 ON T1.COLUMN1=T2.COLUMN2
WHERE t2.id is null
```

Comment: the columns are both on the same table

Comment: @Hilary yes, and this question is using a self join. The problem is that this should return the same results you are already getting

Comment: d'oh, sorry @Lamak - misread. A peril of anonymising your table and column names! Will try.

Comment: Didn't work thanks @Lamak. Can't join on these two columns anyway as they are the numeric values I am trying to compare. They're not unique. I amended the join to be on T2.id = T1.id and moved the column comparison to the WHERE clause but this still didn't work. I still got 3709 rows. Will add your suggestion into question though.

Comment: @Lamak - it's white

Comment: @Hilary if it's white, then it points to it not being a NULL, but a literal string 'NULL'. Are you sure it's an `INT`, can't you get the actual table definition?

Comment: I can't & "is NULL" is now working with no modifications. Infuriated as I HAVE CHANGED NOTHING - even have witnesses! The column comparison is still not working however. I suspect this is to do with the comparison of a NULL to a -99. Forcing the issue with ISNULL(COLUMN1, 99999) makes the comparison work fine which would mean you're likely right about the type but I would have expected the Information Schema views to reflect that. I had been warned that NULLs in SQL Server can be interesting but this??? As data volumes are low, I'm just going to go with that. Thanks for all yr help.